# How to install openERP in ubuntu 13.04 desktop?

Tags: odoo

Is there any better and easy way to install openERP in ubuntu 13.04

I tried so many time but I was unable to set it up?

Help me how to install OPENERP on Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 2):

1. postgresql:

   a.Install postgresql

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgresql
   ```

   b.create a user in postgresql, same name as your login name

   ```
   sudo su postgres
   createuser <login_name> -P
   ```

   or

   ```
   su - postgres -c "createuser -s <login_name>"
   ```
2. Download openerp

   a. Go to  [openerp download page](http://nightly.openerp.com)  and select correct repository or
   b.  wget http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/src/openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz
3. Install python packages needed for openerp

   ```
   apt-get install python-lxml python-mako python-egenix-mxdatetime python-dateutil python-psycopg2 python-pychart python-pydot python-tz python-reportlab python-yaml python-vobject python python-dev python-setuptools build-essential python-CherryPy3 python-pybabel python-formencode python-simplejson python-pyparsing python-gtk2 python-glade2 python-matplotlib python-egenix-mxdatetime python-tz python-hippocanvas python-pydot python-werkzeug python-openid python-webdav python-libxml2 python-lxml python-libxslt1 python-unittest2 python-docutils python-mock python-jinja2
   ```

Now unzip the openerp file that we have downloaded, then go to the openerp unziped folder and run the openerp-server file from a terminal. you can use `./openerp-server` to run.

1. Install IDE(If you want)

   a. Install eclipse

   ```
   sudo apt-get install eclipse
   ```

   b.Add necessary plug-in(python and xml,if needed svn)
       In eclipse,go to Help menu, select install new software,then add repository
       for python,specify location as `http://pydev.org/updates`
       for svn, specify location as `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x`

Answer (score 1):

You can install Bitnami OpenERP Stack, it is very clear and simple to run and also portable because it has all its dependencies in the same folder so if you want to change your computer you have just to copy and paste the directory.

You can download it from [OpenERP Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/openerp).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to install OpenERP 7, download the .deb file and it will install all dependencies.

Find it here: http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/deb/openerp_7.0-latest-1_all.deb