# How to configure openerp7.0?? I can see "Database Management Screen"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 
openerp 7.0
and installed postgreSQL

Please help me for setting up the database. i"m new to openerp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are commands which you can simply copy and paste one by one (since you've already installed just verify them)

**Step 1 - Install Postgres**

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

**Step 2 - change password to postgres user**

```
$ sudo passwd postgres
```

**Step 3 - Login to postgres user**

```
$ su postgres
```

**Step 4 - login to postgres database**

```
$ psql
```

**Step 5 - Create a user for openerp**

```
postgres=# create user openerp70 with password 'yourpassword';
```

**Step 6 - Grant openerp user with create db priviledge**

```
postgres=# alter user openerp70 createdb;
```

**Step 7 - Log out from postgres and restart postgres server**

```
postgres=# \q
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now in **openerp-server.conf** which is located on **your openerp installation dir** / **install**

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = openerp70 
db_password = yourpassword

xmlrpc_port=7575
netrpc_port=7576
```

Now restart the server and create a database by clicking on manage database link on the login page

**Check out these resources for more information**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jRC27vbhN4

[How to install openERP in ubuntu 13.04 desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166536/how-to-install-openerp-in-ubuntu-13-04-desktop)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you!! i just fix the issues before getting this answer.

Comment: those lines are to specify port number to which you connect to openerp. The default one is 8069 which you'd remember by accessing http://localhost:8069/. Now with the above configuration you can access like this http://localhost:7575. And you are free to specify your own port number for openerp server, but make sure there's no other service running on the same port number.